# Time for some TEA!

Tags: code-golf, cryptography

### Introduction

A while back I stumbled across the *tiny encryption algorithm* ([TEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm)) and since then I have recommended it whenever special cryptographic security properties were un-needed and a self-implementation was a requirement.
Now today, we want to take the name **tiny* encryption algorithm* literally and your task will be to implement the *tiniest* encryption algorithm!

### Specification

#### Input

The input is a list of 8 bytes (or your language equivalent), this is the *plaintext*, and another list of 16 bytes (or your language equivalent), this is the *key*.
Input conversion from decimal, hexadecimal, octal or binary is allowed.
 Reading 1 64-bit, 2 32-bit or 4 16-bit integers as output (optionally as a list) is allowed (for the plaintext, double the numbers for the key)

#### Output

The output is a list of 8 bytes (or your language equivalent), this is the *ciphertext*.
Output conversion to decimal, hexadecimal, octal or binary is allowed, but not mandatory.
Writing 1 64-bit, 2 32-bit or 4 16-bit integers as output (optionally as a list) is allowed.

#### What to do?

Your task is to implement the *encryption direction* of the tiny encryption algorithm ([TEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm)), note [XTEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XTEA) and XXTEA are other algorithms.
Wikipedia has a C-code example and a list of references to some implementations in other languages, [this is the original description (PDF)](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=C08E8409ADF484095568965A1EBF3E5E?doi=10.1.1.45.281&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

#### More Formally:

```
Let k1, k2, k3, k4, v1, v2, sum be unsigned 32-bit integers.
(k1,k2,k3,k4) <- key input
(v1,v2) <- plaintext input
sum <- 0
repeat 32 times:
    sum <- ( sum + 0x9e3779b9 ) mod 2^32
    v0  <- ( v0 + ( ((v1 << 4) + k0) XOR (v1 + sum) XOR ((v1 >> 5) + k1) ) ) mod 2^32
    v1  <- ( v1 + ( ((v0 << 4) + k2) XOR (v0 + sum) XOR ((v0 >> 5) + k3) ) ) mod 2^32
output <- (v0,v1)

where 0x9e3779b9 is a hexadecimal constant and
"<<" denotes logical left shift and ">>" denotes logical right shift.
```

#### Potential corner cases

`\0` is a valid character and you may not shorten your input nor output.
Integer encoding is assumed to be little-endian (e.g. what you probably already have).

#### Who wins?

This is code-golf so the shortest answer in bytes wins!
Standard rules apply of course.

### Test-cases

Test vectors were generated using the Wikipedia C code example.

```
Key: all zero (16x \0)
Plaintext -> Ciphertext (all values as two 32-bit hexadecimal words)
00000000 00000000 -> 41ea3a0a 94baa940
3778001e 2bf2226f -> 96269d3e 82680480
48da9c6a fbcbe120 -> 2cc31f2e 228ad143
9bf3ceb8 1e076ffd -> 4931fc15 22550a01
ac6dd615 9c593455 -> 392eabb4 505e0755
ebad4b59 7b962f3c -> b0dbe165 cfdba177
ca2d9099 a18d3188 -> d4641d84 a4bccce6
b495318a 23a1d131 -> 39f73ca0 bda2d96c
bd7ce8da b69267bf -> e80efb71 84336af3
235eaa32 c670cdcf -> 80e59ecd 6944f065
762f9c23 f767ea2c -> 3f370ca2 23def34c
```

Here are some self-generated test vectors with non-zero keys:

```
format: ( 4x 32-bit word key , 2x 32-bit word plaintext ) -> ( 2x 32-bit word ciphertext )
(all in hexadecimal)

( 4300e123 e39877ae 7c4d7a3c 98335923 , a9afc671 79dcdb73 ) -> ( 5d357799 2ac30c80 )
( 4332fe8f 3a127ee4 a9ca9de9 dad404ad , d1fe145a c84694ee ) -> ( a70b1d53 e7a9c00e )
( 7f62ac9b 2a0771f4 647db7f8 62619859 , 618f1ac2 67c3e795 ) -> ( 0780b34d 2ca7d378 )
( 0462183a ce7edfc6 27abbd9a a634d96e , 887a585d a3f83ef2 ) -> ( d246366c 81b87462 )
( 34c7b65d 78aa9068 599d1582 c42b7e33 , 4e81fa1b 3d22ecd8 ) -> ( 9d5ecc3b 947fa620 )
( f36c977a 0606b8a0 9e3fe947 6e46237b , 5d8e0fbe 2d3b259a ) -> ( f974c6b3 67e2decf )
( cd4b3820 b2f1e5a2 485dc7b3 843690d0 , 48db41bb 5ad77d7a ) -> ( b4add44a 0c401e70 )
( ee2744ac ef5f53ec 7dab871d d58b3f70 , 70c94e92 802f6c66 ) -> ( 61e14e3f 89408981 )
( 58fda015 c4ce0afb 49c71f9c 7e0a16f0 , 6ecdfbfa a705a912 ) -> ( 8c2a9f0c 2f56c18e )
( 87132255 41623986 bcc3fb61 7e6142ce , 9d0eff09 55ac6631 ) -> ( 8919ea55 c7d430c6 )
```

Comment: When I tried the Wikipedia C code, using a zero key and plaintext I got the second row of your plaintext as my ciphertext...

Comment: Well, the first two do now; I'm too lazy to try the rest though.

Comment: @Neil, that's the nice thing about crypto: Chances are high, that if a trivial (0-based) and a nontrivial testvector pass, all test vectors will pass :)

Comment: I suggest you add some test cases with a non-zero key.

Comment: @Dennis those can now be found at the bottom of the question :)

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>122</s> <s>118</s> <s>114</s> 113 bytes

```js
f=
(v,w,k,l,m,n)=>{for(s=0;s<84e9;v+=w*16+k^w+s^(w>>>5)+l,w+=v*16+m^v+s^(v>>>5)+n)s+=0x9e3779b9;return[v>>>0,w>>>0]}
;
```

```html
<div oninput="[r0.value,r1.value]=f(...[v0,v1,k0,k1,k2,k3].map(i=>parseInt(i.value,16))).map(i=>(i+(1<<30)*4).toString(16).slice(1))">
Plain 0: <input id=v0><br>
Plain 1: <input id=v1><br>
Key 0: <input id=k0><br>
Key 1: <input id=k1><br>
Key 2: <input id=k2><br>
Key 3: <input id=k3><br>
</div>
Cipher 0: <input id=r0 readonly><br>
Cipher 1: <input id=r1 readonly><br>
```

Note: Uses little-endian arithmetic. Accepts and returns unsigned 32-bit integer values. Edit: Saved 4 bytes by using multiplication instead of left shift. Saved 4 bytes by testing on `s` thus avoiding a separate loop variable. Saved 1 byte by moving the `+=`s inside the `for`.

Comment: Why not use eval with its implicit return instead of return?

Comment: Replacing `{return}` with `eval('')` doesn't save me any bytes

Comment: Oh okay. Thought it save a couple of bytes :(

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, <s>114</s> <s>113</s> 106 bytes

Because Ruby doesn't have 32-bit arithmetic, the extra mod operations caused it to *almost* tie with Javascript anyways despite the other byte-saving operations Ruby has...

- *(-1 byte from extra semicolon)*
- *(-7 bytes from trimming out unnecessary mod operations and shifting stuff around)*

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/C5rG)

```
->v,w,a,b,c,d{s=0
32.times{s+=0x9e3779b9;v+=w*16+a^w+s^w/32+b;v%=m=2**32;w+=v*16+c^v+s^v/32+d;w%=m}
[v,w]}
```

Answer (score 3):

## C, 116 bytes

```c
T(v,w,k,l,m,n,s)unsigned*v,*w;{for(s=0;s+957401312;*v+=*w*16+k^*w+s^*w/32+l,*w+=*v*16+m^*v+s^*v/32+n)s+=2654435769;}
```

Takes plaintext as **v** and **w**; key as **k**, **l**, **m**, and **n**; and stores the ciphertext in **v** and **w**.

Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/0xeHlw).

Answer (score 3):

## J, 149 bytes

```
4 :0
'u v'=.y
s=.0
m=.2x^32
for.i.32
do.s=.m|s+2654435769
u=.m|u+(22 b.)/(s+v),(2{.x)+4 _5(33 b.)v
v=.m|v+(22 b.)/(s+u),(2}.x)+4 _5(33 b.)u
end.u,v
)
```

Yay! explicit (Boo!) J! I think there's a way to do this tacitly, but it'd probably become unreadable.

### Usage

Takes the keys as four 32-bit integers on the LHS and the plaintext as two 32-bit integers on the RHS. The prefix `16b` is equivalent to `0x` in other languages and represents a hex value. The builtin `hfd` formats the output into a hex string for ease in testing.

```
    f =: 4 :0
'u v'=.y
s=.0
m=.2x^32
for.i.32
do.s=.m|s+2654435769
u=.m|u+(22 b.)/(s+v),(2{.x)+4 _5(33 b.)v
v=.m|v+(22 b.)/(s+u),(2}.x)+4 _5(33 b.)u
end.u,v
)
   hfd 0 0 0 0 f 0 0
41ea3a0a
94baa940
   hfd 0 0 0 0 f 16b3778001e 16b2bf2226f
96269d3e
82680480
   hfd 16b4300e123 16be39877ae 16b7c4d7a3c 16b98335923 f 16ba9afc671 16b79dcdb73 
5d357799
2ac30c80
```